# I try to pack my Game in UE5 but it allways fail

Tags: debugging, unreal-engine5, unreal

When i try to pack my Game it allways fail, with this Error:

UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: appError called: Assertion failed: Actor->GetLevel() == this [File:D:\build++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\Level.cpp] [Line: 602]

What can i do ?

I have SDK Installed and Visual Studio,
but it crashes anymway.